# <p:editor> does not show toolbar in Android environment

Tags: android, jsf, primefaces, editor, cleditor

I have a problem with primefaces editor . It run smoothly on my chrome and IE

[image]

However, it does not display its control on my android emulator when I connect to my web on localhost .

[image]

This is my code for it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" ></meta>

        <title>Piccolo Theme</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>


        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.html"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-styles.css"></link>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-ie.css"/>
        <![endif]-->


        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"></link>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png"></link>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"></link>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"></link>


        <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js"/>

        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
       <!-- <script src="js/jquery.custom.js"></script>-->


    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div align="center">
            <h:form rendered="#{userSession.isLogin}">

                You are #{userSession.username}
                <br/>

                Article header: <h:inputText  value="#{userSession.updateArticleTitle}"></h:inputText><br/>

                Article content:<br/>

                <p:editor  width="800" height="800" value="#{userSession.updateArticleContent}"></p:editor><br/>
                <h:commandButton value="Update Article" action="#{userSession.doUpdateArticle}" >
                    <f:param name="articledate" value="#{userSession.updateDate}"></f:param>
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
            <h:form rendered="#{!userSession.isLogin}">
                Please login first !
                <h:link value="Return home" outcome="HomePage"></h:link>
            </h:form>
        </div>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain ? My p:calendar works fine both on web and android emulator but p:editor can't :(